# Why does this code result in an "Object required" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code as a macro in excel. I thought the 2nd line declared the object records and then the 3rd line set it's value. However, I always get an "object Required" error.

```
Sub requiredFill()
  Dim records As Integer
  Set records = Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("B2").Integer
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Set` is only required for an object.  An integer is not an object.

Comment: `Integer` is not a property of a `Range`.  I think you want `Value`.  Try `records = Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("B2").Value`

Comment: `Dim records As Integer` declares a 16-bit integer value.  If you have a 32-bit computer, 16-bit values require special handling and code executes faster with 32-bit values.  `Dim records As Long` declares a 32-bit value.

Comment: Thanks, I did originally have '.Value' but I changed it to integer to see if I could get it to work.

Comment: `Dim records As Long` works! Thanks, should have thought of changing the variable type! @TonyDallimore. Actually no it appeared to work but still comes up with the same error on the 2nd attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try:

```
Set records = Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("B2").Integer
```

or

```
Set records = Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("B2").Value
```

I get the Object required message.

If I try:

```
records = Sheets("Sheet 3").Range("B2").Value
```

I do not.  If you have removed the `Set`, I do not understand your failure.

However:

- You refer to "Sheet 3".  Did you mean "Sheet3".
- Your code relies on cell B2 containing an integer value.

Consider the following

```
Sub requiredFill()
  Dim records As Integer

  With Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2")
    If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
      records = .Value
    Else
      records = 0
    End If
  End With

  Debug.Print records
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this has worked, though I have left the reliance on B2 containing an integer as this is a cell containing the COUNT formula on a hidden and locked sheet.